# How do I troubleshoot a LiveData view on Android where value is always null but record exists with non-null field?

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I'm trying to pull a row from a database using Room and LiveData.

The starting point for my code is:

```
                networkScope.launch {
                    var asset = recordingAssetsViewModel.get(path)
                    runOnUiThread {
                        var dialogText = "Remote URL: ${asset?.value?.remotePath}\n"
                        dialog.setMessage(dialogText)
                        dialog.show()
                    }
                }
```

When I watch in the debugger, path is `/data/user/0/com.xxx.app/files/videos20547.306588963664-screencast.mp4`.

The get function looks like this:

`fun get(path: String) = recordingAssetRepository?.get(path)`

That calls into this:

`fun get(path: String): LiveData<RecordingAsset>? = recordingAssetDao?.findAssetByPath(path)`

That function calls into this:

```
    @Query("select * from video_table where path = :path limit 1")
    fun findAssetByPath(path: String): LiveData<RecordingAsset>
```

As you can see from the image below, that path exists, and the remote_file field has text in it. But, I this `"Remote URL: ${asset?.value?.remotePath}\n"` always becomes `"Remote URL: null\n"` when I run it.

How do I troubleshoot where this is breaking in my app. Is there a way to turn on room debugging so I can see the SQL call it is making (or not making)?

[image: View of database, breakpoint and DB retrieval]

Answer (score 1):

You can't pull data like this from LiveData unless there's a data already. you should observe it using

```
//lifeCycleOwner in Fragment
//this in Activity
asset.observe(lifeCycleOwner) { value->
    runOnUiThread {
        var dialogText = "Remote URL: ${value?.remotePath}\n"
        dialog.setMessage(dialogText)
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

To get the result immediately just remove the LiveData wrapper.

```
@Query("select * from video_table where path = :path limit 1")
    fun findAssetByPath(path: String): RecordingAsset
```

Other than that, just read the LogCat for errors in your sql or room misconfiguration :)